# what's the difference in object code, compiled code and machine code

Tags: compilation

I know machine code is processor specific and is the lowest level and in assuming object code just means a high level language. Where does compiled code fit in? Is it synonymous with machine code?

Comment: Did you check wikipedia for start?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about high-level languages compiled into machine code, such as C and C++<sup>*</sup>, *source code* is said to be compiled into *object code*, which is machine code that needs to be attached to other pieces of machine code (from libraries and other object files) in order to become executable code. The process of stitching pieces of object code together is called *linking*.

Both object code and executable code can be called *compiled code* and *machine code*. "Compiled code" is less specific, because it could mean an intermediate language.

<sup>*</sup> as opposed to high-level languages compiled into intermediate language for execution by a *virtual machine*, such as Java and C#.